# Showing some set is open in a normed vector space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Given $A,B$ two convex subsets of a normed vector space $E$, such that
$A\cap B = \emptyset$. I’m trying to show that if $A$ is open then the set $A-B = \left\lbrace a-b ,\; a\in A, \; b\in B\right\rbrace$ is also open.
I’ve tried to find some way to write this set as a union of open sets but I couldn’t come up with something. I also thought that maybe since $A$ is open, I could find a open ball around $a-b$ given that I have one around $a$ but it doesn’t seem to work, or at least I can’t seem to see how it should work. Any help or hint is appreciated.
(For context, I’m trying to show this as part of the proof of the geometric version of Hahn-Banach’s theorem)

Comment: Why doesn't your approach of finding a ball around $a-b$ from a ball around $a$ "work"?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well it doesn’t seem that the conditions are necessary indeed. This questions is part of a long list of questions and the other did require convexity/disjointness, I struggled with this one for bit and I didn’t really pay attention to what was necessary or not yeah. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

I'm assuming that the topology is the induced metric topology on $E$.  Let $B(a,r)$ be a ball around $a$ in $A$.  Now, consider the ball $B(a-b,r)$, which is a ball around $a-b$.  Let $c\in B(a-b,r)$.  Let $a'=c+b$, then, $\|a'-a\|=\|c-(a-b)\|<r$.  Therefore, $a'\in B(a,r)$ and $c=a'-b\in A-B$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that, fixed $x=a-b\in A-B$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\operatorname{B}(a,\varepsilon)\subset A$, hence the set $$\operatorname{B}(x,\varepsilon)=\operatorname{B}(a,\varepsilon)-b=\{\alpha-b : \alpha\in \operatorname{B}(a,\varepsilon)\}$$
is contained in $A-B$.